flutter WebView: run in Android virtual device, error
Run WebView_flutter widget in Android virtual device:
WebViewController controller = WebViewController()
  ..loadHtmlString('Hello World');

return WebViewWidget(controller: controller);

Error:
════════ Exception caught by services library ══════════════════════════════════
InstanceManager does not contain a WebChromeClient with instanceId: 9
'package:webview_flutter_android/src/android_webview_api_impls.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1042 pos 7: 'instance != null'

